# C - reassigning pointer which is attribute of struct: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type

Tags: c, pointers, struct, doubly-linked-list

I'm reasonably certain that I have a horrible understanding of pointers in C (at least syntactically).

I am trying to have a struct which is a linkedlist with a bunch of data. Later, I try to add a new struct as the head of that linkedlist, pointing to the old head, which has a "prior" link to the new head.

```
typedef struct{
  int sequence_number;
  int file_descriptor;
  FILE *requested_file;
  int bytes_remaining;
  int quantum;
  struct RCB *next;
  struct RCB *prior;
} RCB;

   RCB *RRhead;
...


function blah(){
  RCB new_rcb = {sequence_counter, fd, fin, new_bytes_remaining, new_quantum, RRhead, NULL};
  RRhead->prior = &new_rcb;
  RRhead = &new_rcb;
  sequence_counter++;
}
```

And I am getting these errors:

```
sws.c: In function ‘admit_to_scheduler_RR’:
sws.c:317:3: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
   RCB new_rcb = {sequence_counter, fd, fin, new_bytes_remaining, new_quantum, RRhead, NULL};
sws.c:317:3: warning: (near initialization for ‘new_rcb.next’) [enabled by default]
sws.c:318:17: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
   RRhead->prior = &new_rcb;
```

Comment: What is `new_rcb`?

Comment: Give me a moment to fix it.

Comment: If `new_rcb` is an `RCB` and `RRhead` is an `RCB *`, then `RRhead = new_rcb;` doesn't make sense.

Comment: try removing the word 'struct' from the line 'struct RCB *RRhead;'

Comment: Please post a MCVE,  the large number of partial snippets is getting messy

Comment: Should I post that as a separate question? These snippets are all the same lines of code, after suggested modifications. I can remove the old versions.
@matt I did so and I am still getting two errors.

Comment: just have the one line: RCB new_rcb = {sequence_counter, fd, fin, new_bytes_remaining, new_quantum, NULL, *RRhead};  and that should fix the first error,  see the answer from n.m. to fix the other

Comment: So you're saying all of this is inside `main()` ? Or what.

Comment: It's all in a function which is called from main.

Comment: OK, you should move the struct definition and `typedef` to be outside of any function.  Also, if you are putting `&new_rcb` into a list which is meant to keep existing when the function returns, you have a whole lot more problems ahead f you

Comment: ... oh dear.

The typedef was always outside of any function.

Comment: What is the best practice for getting new solutions, implementing them, and getting new errors? Opening a new question or constantly modifying the original?

Comment: Good practice would be to read a book or browse other questions, and only post (or repost) here as a last resort... the main idea of this site is to have questions that will be useful to other people as well who have a similar problem in future.  Not a crowdsourced debugger. As you have it now it's a matter of choosing the lesser of two evils... editing a question that's already been answered makes it confusing for newcomers reading the question. Posting a new question is probably best but remember to include a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so people aren't guessing about details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of problems here. It's not clear exactly what your real code is since you keep changing it but I'll have a crack:

---

First of all, in C, struct tags are in a separate "namespace" to typedef names. There is no relation between `struct RCB` and `RCB`. Particularly, in this code:

```
typedef struct {
  struct RCB *next;
  struct RCB *prior;
} RCB;
```

`next` does NOT point to a `RCB`. It points to a `struct RCB` which is a completely different type to `RCB`. This is why you get the error `error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type` . You never defined what `struct RCB` is.

If you want a struct containing pointers to itself, you *must* use a struct tag, because the typedef name does not exist until the typedef is complete. For example:

```
struct RCB
{
    // ...
    struct RCB *next, *prior;
};

typedef struct RCB RCB;
```

Of course, the typedef is optional; and *could* be combined with the struct definition but I think it is clearer to separate the two.

---

The next problem is:

```
new_rcb = {sequence_counter, fd, fin, new_bytes_remaining, new_quantum, RRhead, NULL};
```

This is not allowed in C, the right-hand side of the assignment operator must be an expression. A brace-enclosed list is not an expression. The simplest way to avoid this problem is to use initialization:

```
RCB new_rcb = {sequence_counter, fd, fin, new_bytes_remaining, new_quantum, RRhead, NULL};
```

---

Another runtime problem is hinted at in the latest edit:

```
function blah(){
  RCB new_rcb = {sequence_counter, fd, fin, new_bytes_remaining,  new_quantum, RRhead, NULL};
  RRhead->prior = &new_rcb;
  RRhead = &new_rcb;
  sequence_counter++;
}
```

Obviously this is some sort of pseudocode. But `new_rcb` is a local variable to the `blah` function.  `new_rcb` stops existing when `blah` returns.  This means the list pointed to by `RRhead` will contain a dangling pointer.

When using pointers you need to have a very clear mental image of where pointers are pointing and what the lifetime is of the objects being pointed to.

To fix this you could either use dynamic allocation (`malloc`), or some sort of memory pool.

Comment: I implemented all of these and I'm still getting a ton of errors. I'm going to post a new question.

Comment: OK. Make sure to include a MCVE and try to remove irrelevant details, e.g. if you get the same error with a struct only contianing 1 int and 2 pointers then that would cut down on the noise level.

Answer (score 3):

`RCB` and `struct RCB` are two completely different, unrelated types. `struct RCB` is never defined in your code and is hence incomplete.

To make them one and the same, write

```
typedef struct RCB {
   ....
} RCB;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one part of the problem.

Don't use  `*RRhead` when initializing `new_rcb`. You just want `RRhead`.

The struct has a pointer, i.e. `struct RCB *prior` so you must use the pointer `RRhead`.

Comment: I'm still getting the above errors (among tons - not an exhaustive list.)

Comment: No, `RRhead` is a pointer. `*RRhead` is a dereference of the pointer, i.e. should be a `struct RCB`

Comment: OK, I understand. I'm still having the errors in the question.

Answer (score 1):

firstly, RRhead is just a pointer, so when you go RRhead->prior, you will get a runtime error, because RRhead isn't pointing to anything  (RRhead->prior says "get the 'prior'property of the RCB struct that RRhead is pointing to)

secondly, when you pass *RRhead as the last initializer of new_rcb: prior is an RCB pointer, and RRhead is an RCB pointer. they are the same type, so there is no need to do any referencing or dereferencing, just pass RRhead. this will make the prior property of new_rcb point to whatever RRhead is pointing to at the time (which is nothing at that moment, because RRhead hasn't been initalized to any value)

thirdly, RRhead->prior = new_rcb; is wrong because 'prior' is an RCB pointer, whereas new_rcb is not a pointer, it is a RCB.  to pass the adress of new_rcb, go RRhead->prior = &new_rcb;

Finally, its unlikely you will want new_rcb to be statically allocated.

Comment: RRhead may already be pointing at something by the time this code occurs. How can I prevent it from causing a runtime error if it's not pointing at anything by this point?

Also, I'm not sure what you mean by statically allocated; are you implying that I should use malloc here? How would I do so? What would the consequences of static allocation be?

Comment: initialize it to NULL, then check if it is null before doing things.

Also, in your initialization of new_rcb, I think it is the 'next' property that should be being set to RRHead, and 'prior' that is set to NULL?

Comment: specifically, if you initialize RRhead to null, you just need to wrap the RRhead->prior = &new_rcb; line around an if(RRhead!=NULL) check

Comment: Implemented your fixes and I'm still getting errors. Posting them.